# Solr communication with HTTP

Tags: java, solr, weblogic

I have integrated solr.war in my web application, i am using bea102 weblogic server. 
Now my question is :
1. How to make communication with HTTP ,of this solr web application.
2. My application is running on port 7001, and new solr search application will run on 8983, what changes are i need to do .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These questions aren't really about Solr, but here goes anyway.

1. If your application deployed correctly you should be able to access it on `host:7001/solr`. Otherwise refer to your weblogic manual how to deploy war files.
2. You need to send your web request to `host:8983/solr`.

Comment: i am able to access my application on 7001 but my solr search is not running on 8983. i wanted to ask how shuld i deploy both web (solr search web application and my ECommerce application) both at the same web server.